# Time derivative of Boltzmann's entropy functional: Putting the time differentiation into the integrand

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I have a rather naive question concerning the entropy functional of Boltzmann,
$$
H[f] = \int f(v,t)\ln f(v,t)\, dv.
$$
Its time derivative is (see, for example, [here](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/plasma/Plasma/node35.html))
$$
\frac{\partial H[f]}{\partial t}=\int\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(\ln f+1)\, dv.
$$

That is, the differentiation is put into the integrand.

Why is this possible?
Is this some kind of multidimensional Leibniz rule where some of the terms vanish?

Comment: to be sure that you may exchange the order of an integral and of a limit (the limit in your case is the derivative), you can use the Dominated Convergence Theorem

Comment: No [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) unless you mistakenly think that the integration bounds depend on $t$. I recommend to read better books/papers on the subject where they use a clearer notation for their integrals.

Comment: @KurtG. Ok, no Leibniz rule. The integration bounds do **not** depend on time. But why can I put the time differentiation into the integrand then?

Comment: If you have trouble with that you must pedantically apply what user8268 mentioned in the first comment. Being an applied mathematician for almost 30 years now I have the freedom to just do it. :)

Comment: Indeed, I have problems to apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem. If I am not mistaken, I have to show that (1) $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(\ln f+1)$ is integrable and (2) that 
$$
\left\vert \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(\ln f+1)\right\vert\leq g
$$
for an integrable function $g$. I have no idea to do so.

Comment: The web page you are reading up there says nothing about the properties of $f\,.$ Afaik functions that don't allow to pull the differentiation into the integrand are counterexamples of the sort that rarely occur in practice. You should study that separately in a very good analysis book. For the entropy stuff just get on with assuming you can do it.